# CheckBox android studio

Tags: android, checkbox

Como consigo mostrar meu checkbox já marcado com valor recuperado do código.

consegui recuperar o valor

```
checkBox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check1);
```

e guardei em um var

```
if (checkBox1.isChecked()){
  check1InputLayout = "1";
  }else{
  check1InputLayout = "0";
  }
```

queria mostrar no meu XML o valor true ou false de acordo com o resultado do check

Comment: Não entendi o que quer... Exibir "1" ou "0" como texto de algum controle da sua tela?

Comment: Preciso mostrar o check box marcado quando recupero minha lista

Comment: Para marcar o check box seria `checkBox1.setChecked(true)`

Comment: Mas para guardar este valor utilizo statement ou posso salvar em objeto do banco?